# MASM - Entering Privilege Level 0

Tags: assembly, intel

How do I enter the privilege level 0 in Microsoft Assembler? 
Intel x86, Windows 10.

This is what I tried (it did not compile/assemble):

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
    
.code

main PROC
    mov eax, 1
    call IA32_PL0_SSP ;undefined symbol IA32_PL0_SSP
    out 1, eax ;privileged instruction -> exception

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What kind of program? User-mode application? Kernel-driver? Why do you want to enter PL 0?

Comment: @Sebastian I want to write a program that communicates with the hardware directly without using microsoft APIs. For example trying to receive the temperature of the CPU or printing characters to the screen without using windows system calls.

Comment: Windows will prevent you to interfere with the system. Would it suit your use case to execute your program at boot time and not starting Windows? Then you can read machine status registers, output ports and write on the screen with BIOS calls. Alternatively, if you just want to execute those instructions without actually interfacing directly with the hardware, a virtual environment would be an option. If you just want to have full power to explore the system: Even PL0 is not allowed to do everything on modern CPUs. Please read about System Management Mode and Intel Management Engine.

Comment: @Sebastian To execute the program at boot time and not starting Windows would be fine, but if my program does not assemble and/or link I will not get an .exe file and how will I then be able to boot from that? I will read up on that.

Comment: Then I would recommend creating a real mode program. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode - Real mode has no privilege levels. So you can leave out the line, which does not compile. You could start real mode programs from DOS, e.g. FreeDOS. There is plenty of information how to create DOS programs with masm.